# Emacs auto-scrolling log buffer

Tags: logging, emacs

I am watching a development log in Emacs. However whenever I open this log it opens in fundamental mode and the buffer does not scroll with the content of the log. It should be noted that this is very low volume log that only collects information on the errors I make when writing source. Its very convenient for me to see this in Emacs since the log responds to command I enter in the editor. How do I get a buffer than scrolls with my log?

Comment: What mode are you using for what you are editing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then do a `(set (make-local-variable 'window-point-insertion-type) t)` inside this log buffer.  If the cursor is then placed at the end of the buffer, it should stay there (at the end) when text is appended, thus causing scrolling as needed.

Comment: Note that this only works if you're in evil insert mode. (If using evil, of course.)

Comment: It should work regardless, but indeed it's likely/possible that Evil prevents you from going to the end of the buffer when you're not in insert-mode.  IIRC in Viper this is configurable, so maybe the same applies to Evil.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't ask a question but I guess you want to use [auto-revert-tail-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoRevertMode).

Comment: While your solution is a cool thing to know indeed. I cannot use it because the buffer is not visiting a file (or at least that is what the mode says when I try to initialize it). The buffer is being populated directly by another running Emacs process.